# How do I show that this set is open, closed or neither?

Tags: real-analysis

$$X=\left\lbrace(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x < 3, 0 \leq y \leq 1\right\rbrace$$

The book I am following is a little vague on this.

My initial thought is to show that since that there is no ball $$B((0,0),r)$$ with $r>0$ that contains every point of $X$ then the set is not open.

Comment: Your initial though isn't quite right. For example if $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ then there is no ball containing every point of $X$, but $X$ *is* open.

Answer (score 3):

With your initial thought you were close to the answer. $(0,0) \in X$ and for all $r >0$ there is an element outside of $X$ in $B((0,0),r)$. So $X$ is not open.

$X$ is not closed either. Take the following sequence $a_n=(3-\frac{1}{n},1)$. $a_n \in X$ for all $n$, but 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} a_n = (3,1) \not\in X$$
Since the limit of a converging sequence of elements of $X$ is not in $X$, it is not closed.

Conclusion $X$ is neither closed, nor open.